# python: model: can an attribute reference an attribute from the same model?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, models

(*this question will probably win the dumbiest question prize, but I'll give it a try*)

I have a simple menu class in my models:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False,unique=True,max_length=50)
url = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True,max_length=100)
sortOrder = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
```

this will happily let me build one level of menu items.

If I wanted to go further and add another level, how do I make an items reference and id from the same model and make sure this id is not the id of the same item?

so there are actually two questions:

**1.** how do I set the ForeignKey to and id from the same class? Referencing neither Menu or self won't get validated:

```
class Menu(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False,unique=True,max_length=50)
url = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True,max_length=100)
sortOrder = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
**parent = models.ForeignKey(Menu)**
```

will throw:

NameError: name 'Menu' is not defined

**2.** how do I make sure this item's id is not the id of this item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try self

```
parent = models.ForeignKey( 'self' )
```

Comment: this worked - for the second part of the question - do I just assume that before the record is inserted I won't be able to reference this exact record and if I update it to do so later on I'm just a silly myself? :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If some of your menus will not have parent menus, you may need `models.ForeignKey( 'self', null = True )` Then if a menu doesn't have a parent you will know it's a top level menu. I'm still little confused by "I'm just a silly myself".